# Determine whether this improper integral converges or not

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

The expression is: 
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x-e^{-x}}dx$$
I know that to prove if the the integral converges, it must have a limit and if it diverges it doesn't. I have gotten to this bit:
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x-e^{-x}}dx=\lim_{t\to \infty}\int_1^t\frac{1}{x-e^{-x}}dx$$
But I have no idea how to integrate $\int_1^t\frac{1}{x-e^{-x}}dx$ to find the limit to see if it converges or not. Are there any tests I can use instead to see if it converges or not?

Comment: You can try a comparison test with integration of a simpler function.  If $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x \geq 1$ then $\int_1^{\infty} f(x)dx \leq \int_1^{\infty} g(x)dx$.

Comment: What function could I use?

Comment: You can try some simple related functions.  Ones you can integrate and/or that you know converge or diverge.

Comment: Your integral does not converge.

Comment: How did you work that out?

Comment: Use the 2nd (limit) comparison test with 1/x

Comment: @M.Calculator Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

This is not a "detailed proof" but I feel that it is sufficient. As mentioned, using a comparison test would give you your answer. For example consider the function: $g(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}$. It is easy to see that $$\frac{1}{x + 1}\leq\frac{1}{x-e^{-x}}$$ for all $x \geq 1$. We know that $$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x + 1}dx = \infty.$$ Because your function $\frac{1}{x-e^{-x}}$ is bounded below by a integral that diverges, it also diverges, which means:$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x-e^{-x}}dx=\infty.$$

Comment: how does $$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x + 1}dx = \infty.$$ tend towards infinity and not 0?

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\frac{1}{x-e^{-x}}\sim \frac 1x$$

therefore the given integral diverges by [**limit comparison test**](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/SeriesCompTest.aspx) with $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}dx$.

As an alternative note that

$$\frac{1}{x-e^{-x}}\ge \frac 1x$$

then the given integral diverges also by comparison test.